# v-for loop is not working in nuxt 3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am trying to bind some mock data saved in a variable called whatsHappeningItems that I have in my script as a ref to send into a card component I have. When I do the v-for="whatsHappening in whatsHappeningItems" as shown:

I get this error message:

[vue/valid-v-for]
Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives.

```
const whatsHappening: {
title: string;
count: string;
```

}

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share your `v-for` code?

Comment: Yes, my latest answer is the answer and solution to the problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `eslint` add something like this

```js
<...
  v-for="(whatsHappening, index) in whatsHappeningItems"
  :key="index"
  ....
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, I got error on the first pharanteses that says: Array element destructuring pattern expected.

I tried doing:

v-for="whatsHappening in whatsHappeningItems" v-bind:key="whatsHappening"

and all errors were removed, but maybe this is not a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a eslint issue as stated by Tachibana Shin

I wrote:

```js
<...
v-for="whatsHappening in whatsHappeningItems" v-bind:key="whatsHappening" 
  ....
```

And my mock data looks like this:

```js
<...
<script setup>
const whatsHappeningItems = ref([
  {
    title: 'example',
    count: 'example',
  },
]);
</script>

  ....
```

all errors were removed so it seems to have fixed the issue.